# Я расположил 3 видео в ряд. Но они вообще не по центру. Как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, frontend

вот мой html код:

```
<div class="container-3">
    <div class="brd">
        <video width=33% height=33% controls src="./video/one.mp4" class="video-1"></video>
        <video width=33% height=33% controls src="./video/two.mp4" class="video-2"></video>
        <video width=33% height=33% controls src="./video/tree.mp4" class="video-3"></video>            
    </div>
</div>
```

а вот мой css код:

```
.container-3 {
    margin-top: 410px;
    min-width: 1680;
    min-height: 310;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.brd {
    margin-top: 410;
}
```

А вот то, что у меня получилось этим кодом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и мне надо убрать вот эту херню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.brd { margin: 410px auto 0 auto}` Единицы измерения указывайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое!